# Using yeoman 1.0b, the grunt server's livereload functionality does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, gruntjs, livereload

i am trying to get yeoman running again on my mac. with 1.0 beta i do get this confusing error which even is present when i restart my mac. in earlier versions i would start yeoman server and then just hit control+c to terminate it. when i wanted the server again, i would just do yeoman start again. i think the problem is that livereload is not shut down correctly (or still running), but i dont know how to shut it down properly.

```
grunt start

.... some yeoman log ....

... Uhoh. Got error listen EADDRINUSE ...
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1022:14)
    at listen (net.js:1044:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1110:5)
    at Server.listen (/Users/theuser/web/2013/project/node_modules/grunt-contrib-livereload/node_modules/tiny-lr/lib/server.js:133:15)
    at Object.startLRServer (/Users/theuser/web/2013/project/node_modules/grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/theuser/web/2013/project/node_modules/grunt-contrib-livereload/tasks/livereload.js:44:20)
    at Object.thisTask.fn (/Users/theuser/web/2013/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:78:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/theuser/web/2013/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:282:30)
    at Task.runTaskFn (/Users/theuser/web/2013/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:235:24)
```

ps: my ultimate goal is to get yeoman's to run sass 3.3 pre running with sourcemap support. i guess you need to configure sass from the gruntfile, but i have no clue how to do that, too.

any help deeply appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too late but I was having the same problem and it turned out that I had another instance of Grunt server running on port 9000. All I did was disconnect that session and try again.